# ERROR: "timers cannot be started from another thread" Using QFuture with no timers declared

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Im using QFuture to add threads to my ui application, i call a method from one thread and have a watcher and signal set so that when the first function is finished a second one is called

both use the same code to thread the function off

first use of QFuture

```
future = QtConcurrent::run(&Test, &test::getAll);


watcher->setFuture(*future);
```

second use of QFuture

```
*future2 = QtConcurrent::run(this, &GUI::paintAll);

watcher2->setFuture(*future2);
```

when this second one is called i get this warning

```
QObject::startTimer: timers cannot be started from another thread
```

and then it sometimes will crash sometimes it wont but i just cant help but feel its to do with this, iv asked so many questions about this now without answers that work, could someone please tell me why im being warned about timers when im not even using them, also why im warned only the second time i call a qfuture function never on that first one??

Comment: dont know if commenting "Bumps" this thread but seriously cant believe this is dead without so much as a grammar nazi-ing even....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Qt, GUI classes must only be accessed by the main thread (it's also called the "GUI thread"). You cannot run paint functions in another thread. See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread

I'm guessing that GUI::paintAll() indirectly calls Qt GUI classes, which use timers internally.

Comment: i have no GUI functions being called from within a thread, but its ok the crashing was due to something else so if its just a warning i guess ill just leave it

Comment: The warning indicates that Qt tried to do something but failed. Whatever was meant to be done when the timer times out will never get done.

What does GUI::paintAll() do?

Comment: it really doesnt matter because im not even using timers anyway, if the worst that happens is that a message prints to console on run that doesnt affect my program then im not too bothered, the crashing was because of something else thats fixed now